# How can I fix "The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm creating the platform falling effect by unchecking the isKinematic but I keep getting the error :
"MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Here is my code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision){
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Fall();
        Invoke("Fall", 0.2f); //delay 0.2 s chu y dau va viet thuong
    }
}

void Fall(){
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
    Destroy(gameObject,1f);

}
```

}
[Here is the error in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGbmB.png)

Can anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: why call `Fall` twice? first you call it and then you invoke it with .2 delay. Seems that in the second call the gamebject was destroyed already. You would need to fix that or check i f the gameObject is null before destroying it, to destroy it only in the case it is not null :)

Comment: I just tested the code and it works fine for me. But I think it has something to do with what @rustyBucketBay already said. You are calling the method twice. Is the above code your exact code that you are using?

Comment: @DanielM yes the above code is the exact code that I am using. So I just need to delete the Fall() and using Invoke("Fall", 0.2f); right.

Comment: @TalonTài Yes, you should definitely try that.

Comment: @DanielM Thank you I delete the Fall() and reset unity and it works lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of your current code is as following:

- Called **Fall()** once (After 1 second from that call the gameObject will be destroyed).
- You are using Invoke to call **Fall()** after **0.2 seconds** while you have already a task to destroy the gameObject from the first call.

**Update:** I assumed that you want to set kinematic false **immediately**. I updated the piece of code :)

---

**Code**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Q69205071 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //Fall(1f);
            /// since you want everything to be executed after 0.2 seconds
            /// you could use Invoke or coroutines.
            Invoke("Fall", 0.2f); 
        }
    }

    private void Fall()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        Destroy(gameObject, 1f); // 1 seconds delay before destroying the gameObject
    }
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: **Your code does not produce the same behaviour that OP's code produces.** In OP's code the platform will wait 0.2 seconds **until** it falls down. Then it will destroy itself after 1 second, taking **1.2 seconds** all in all. In your code the platform will fall down **immediatly** and gets destroyed after 1 second.

Comment: @DanielM True!  I assumed that they want to disable kinematic right away :) Updated the answer.